# Alternative way of saying "calling a spade a spade"

Tags: idioms, slang, idiom-requests

I found this expression curt and powerful. But I also understand it's offensive to someone, and somehow, has a racist implication.

Is there a similar curt and powerful expression I can use without offending anybody?

Comment: Some context would be useful.

Comment: Ironically, the original author (can't remember who) from long ago had zero racial implications whatsoever when he said that. The original quote says something like "Call a spade a spade and a niggard a niggard". Niggard is an archaic term for a stingy or ungenerous person and has nothing to do with black people or the N-Word. But over the years this has been mistakenly viewed as a racist term and by association, so has spade. I know this doesn't answer the OP's request for an alternative expression, but I thought the background was interesting to share.

Comment: You may have found it curt and powerful, but you also found it incorrect. The actual expression is a fixed phrase and contains only indefinite articles. I.e, _calling a spade a spade_ is correct; _the spade_ is not.

Comment: I've often heard "calling a spade a fucking shovel".

Comment: I don't think there is a black or white answer in regards to the possible offense.  That being said, asking for alternatives seems a reasonable request regardless of the reason.

Answer (score 7):

***[Telling it like it is](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tell+it+like+it+is)*** is an informal idiom that has gained popularity lately, I think.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use "***straight talk***" as an alternative.

Wiktionary:

> **[straight talk](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/straight_talk)**
>   **Simple, honest speaking.**
>
> **[call a spade a spade](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/call_a_spade_a_spade#English)**
>   (*idiomatic*) **To
>   speak the truth; to say things as they really are.**

Also, couple of other idioms (using the word "*straight*"): "***straight from the shoulder***" & "***give it to someone straight***".

TFD(idioms):

> **[straight from the shoulder](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/straight+from+the+shoulder)**  (*American*)
>   if you speak straight from the shoulder, you speak directly and honestly
>   I gave it to him
>   straight from the shoulder. 'You're talking garbage,' I said.
>   (*American*)
>
> Cambridge Idioms Dictionary, 2nd ed. Copyright © Cambridge University
>   Press 2006. Reproduced with permission.
>
> **[give it to someone (straight)](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/give+it+to)** to tell something to someone clearly and directly.
>   Come on, give it to me straight. I want to
>   know exactly what happened.
>   Quit wasting time, and tell me. Give it to
>   me straight.
>
> McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs. © 2002 by
>   The McGraw-Hill Companies, Inc.